# Firebase Android - Able to write data to Realtime Database but not read back

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing to the realtime database in a method using

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Test");
        myRef.setValue("test");
```

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2IQI.jpg)

[image]

Later on I am trying to retrieve this string in another method using

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Test");

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

I want value to read "test" but it always returning null.

Comment: Have you tried to log the result `Log.d(TAG, value);`? Have you also tried to log the error?

Comment: mRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Test") i have added an answer also . your reference is wrong i think

Answer (score 0):

Use this technique to resolve your issue

```
   mRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Test")
 ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
          value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("yourtag ", " Result= "value);

        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
};
mRef.addValueEventListener(listener);
```